# Referencing the next row for evaluate and index match

Tags: vba, excel

I have this formula

```
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Sheets("Tab 1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Range("AP2:AP" & lastrow)

.Value = Evaluate("=IFERROR(INDEX('Usages'!A:G,MATCH(1,('Usages'!F:F=""No"")*('Usages'!C:C=N2)*('Usages'!D:D<=AO2)*('Usages'!E:E>=AO2),0),2),""Not Found"")")

End With
```

How do i make it so that my match function refers to the next row
e.g. N2,N3 AO2,AO3
Currently i am only getting values based of arguments from N2 and AO2 for the whole column.

This formula is placed in a separate sheet from Usages.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
dim ulr as long, lastrow As Long

lastrow = Sheets("Tab 1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

with worksheets("Usages")
    ulr = .cells(.rows.count, "B").end(xlup).row
end with

With Worksheets("Tab 1").Range("AP2:AP" & lastrow)
    .Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Usages'!B:B, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$" & ulr & ")/" & _
                   "(('Usages'!F$1:F$" & ulr & "=""No"")*('Usages'!C$1:C$" & ulr & "=N2)*('Usages'!D$1:D$" & ulr & "<=AO2)*('Usages'!E$1:E$" & ulr & ">=AO2)), 1)), ""Not Found"")"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: Sorry I was not clear with the question. What im trying to do is so to change the N2 --> N3..N4..N5 ('Usages'!C:C=N2)  and this formula is placed in a different sheet from Usages.

Comment: I realize that. Without a parent worksheet reference, the formula will be an array formula on the activesheet. I need to reference Usages to cut your full column references down to the used range. That determination is independent of the formula placement although I would suggest adding a parent worksheet to Range("AP2:AP" & lastrow).

Comment: Ah i see, i have followed your suggestions. However I am still getting the value from the arguments in N2 and AO2.

Comment: Oh, yeah ... the formula is going in as an array formula block. I'll try to think of a non-array formula.

Comment: Im just a student trying to learn vba. Thank you for your patience and help.

Comment: Standard formula added.